# InstallShield 2012: Trying to run an InstallScript custom action during uninstall but getting error

Tags: installshield

I have an InstallScript function that runs fine when running during the install that I need to run during an uninstall.  It is backing up the existing applications.  I created a Custom Action for it and added it to the Execute Sequence after InstallValidate.

There is no log file generated, as far as I can tell for uninstalls, so I am having trouble figuring out why it fails with a "Feature Transfer Error" -1603.

I am pretty sure the function is not being called as I put a MessageBox as the first thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the Install UI Condition or Install Exec Condition to

```
(REMOVE="ALL")OR(REMOVE="<feature_being_uninstalled>")
```

just in case you have or will in the future have multiple features being installed.  (Unless of course, you only want to run the Custom Action in the case where the whole product is being uninstalled)

Answer (score 0):

To run a custom action during uninstall, set its condition to `REMOVE="ALL"` in Install UI Condition or Install Exec Condition, which ever is applicable in your case.

To run a custom action when a product is already installed, the condition should be set to `Installed`.

To run a custom action when a product is not installed, the condition should be set to `Not Installed`.

I believe you can use the following [msiexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command to log the uninstall:

```
msiexec /x YourProduct.msi /L*v logfile.txt
```

or

```
msiexec /x {Your Product/Package Code} /L*v logfile.txt
```

Comment: I should also mention that it is an InstallScript MSI project

Comment: There error I saw does not look like it came from my custom action.  I somehow got my install in a state with IS could not unintall it.  I got it back to a working state and now the custom action is called.  I did add the Condition of 'REMOVE="ALL"'